# How to export the entire active records in a schema to a csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to achieve exporting the entire active records in a rails application to csv where each relation is a sheet of csv or there is another way to export full db data.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def backup
models = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
all_data = Hash.new
models.map do |model_name|
  table_data = []
  model_name = model_name.split("")
  model_name.pop
  model_name = model_name.join("")
  model_name.camelize.constantize.all.map do |data|
    table_data.push(data)
  end
  all_data[model_name.camelize] = table_data
end
send_data export_csv(all_data), filename: "Backup - #{Date.today}.csv" and return
end
def export_csv(data)
 csvfile = CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
  data.each do |key, value|
    csv << [key]
    attributes  = key.camelize.constantize.column_names
    csv << attributes
    value.each do |val|
      csv << val.attributes.values_at(*attributes)
    end
    csv << ['eot']
  end
 end
 return csvfile
 end
```

I found the solution and a way to export all tables inside a single csv file.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this you can get datas from your tables. after you can split it by sheet

```js
models = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
models.shift
models.shift
models.map do |model_name|
model_name = model_name.split("")
model_name.pop
model_name = model_name.join("")
    model_name.camelize.constantize.all.map do |data|
       puts data
    end
end
```

Comment: I dont know how to write sheet by sheet in csv. you can write your own

Comment: i will try this one and try to enhance it if posible... thank you any way for your answer